# perl: print to console all the matched pattern

Tags: perl

I have mulitple lines

```
QQQQl123

hsdhjhksd

QQQQl234

ajkdkjsdh

QQQQl564
```

i want to print all matching QQQQl[0-9]+

like

```
QQQQl123 
QQQQl234 
QQQQl564
```

how to do this using perl

I tried:

```
$ perl -0777pe '/QQQQl[0-9]+/' filename
```

it shows nothing

Comment: i wanted to know how to do with perl

Comment: perl -we 'while(<>){ next unless $_=~/QQQQl[0-9]+/; print $_; }' < filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print if /QQQQl[0-9]+/' filename
```

Or, if, for some reason, you insist on using `-0777`, you could do

```
perl -0777nE 'say for /QQQQl[0-9]+/g' filename
```

(or `print "$_\n"` instead of `say`)

Your code doesn't work because `/QQQQl[0-9]+/` returns true because `$_` indeed contains that pattern, but you never asked Perl to do anything based on that return value.

`-n` is preferable to `-p` in that case, since you don't want to print every line but only some (`-p` automatically prints every line, and there is very little you can do about it).

Comment: i was having some other case and tried `$ perl -0777nE 'say for /^JWQL(?!JWQL|QWWK).*^QWWK/g' filename` But it does not work. Here `^JWQL(?!JWQL|QWWK).*^QWWK` will match between ^JWQL and ^QWWK and does not contain inbetween JWQL or QWWK (which are not in the beginning). But it does not work

Answer (score 1):

`perl -we 'while(<>){ next unless $_=~/QQQQl[0-9]+/; print $_; }' < filename`

Comment: what is -we. Also some patterns may match multiline in that case what to do

Comment: `-w` enables warnings, which isn't very useful here. `while(<>){ ... }` should be done with `-n` instead. `< filename` could just be `filename`. `$_=~/QQQQl[0-9]+/` would be as clear and more concise as `/QQQQl[0-9]+/`.